# What is the proper way to implement the Repository Pattern ? and How to use it ?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern, mvp

I have an object called `Product` and I want to retrieve the "Bill Of Material" for a certain product from the list of all products (stored in SQL Server). Should I first create the Product object then get the data from my repository thru a method, like this:

```
var productId = "1";
Product product = new Product(productId);
DataTable billOfMaterial = product.GetBillOfMaterial();
```

OR retrieve the data strait from a static Repository, like this:

```
var productId = "1";
DataTable billOfMaterial = product.GetBillOfMaterial(productId);
```

OR maybe like this?

```
var productId = "1";
DataTable BillOfMaterial = ProductRepository.GetBillOfMaterial(productId);
```

OR maybe when I create the Product I automatically get the Bill in the constructor of the product:

```
var productId = "1";
Product product = new Product(productId);
DataGrid.DataSource = product.BillOfMaterial;
```

I am using the MVP pattern, and don't know if it is best practice to fill object just to get the `DataTable` or if I can just quickly use a static repository. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before implementing the repository design pattern, you should first know why we do implement it. and the answer to the question is:

- Minimizes duplicate query logic.
- Decouples your application from persistence frameworks (i.e. Entity Framework..) so that you can switch to a new persistence framework without having any effects on your main application as all the changes will be held on the Data Access Layer.
- Promotes testability (mocking data will be much simpler and easier).

So, Now let's discuss the implementation : 
The proper way to implement the repository pattern would be to implement an Interface `IProductRepository` that will contain the signatures of the methods that will be implemented in your `ProductRepository`. Also, this is the interface that you will be needing in order to inject it directly to your IoC Container.
So, your `IProductRepository` should look like this :

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetBillOfMaterialById(string productId);
}
```

and your `ProductRepository` should look like this :

```
public class DeviceHistoryRepository : IDeviceHistoryRepository
{

    public DeviceHistoryRepository(DbContext context)
    {
         Context = context;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Course> GetBillOfMaterialById(string productId)
    {
        return dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == ProductId);
    }
}
```

Then from your Presenter, you can inject your repository through its constructor :

```
public class ProductPresenter: Presenter
{
    #region Declaration
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;
    #endregion
    public ProductPresenter(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        #region Initialization
        _productRepository = productRepository;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then you can access it from your Presenter's Actions / Methods like this :

```
Product product = _productRepository.GetBillOfMaterialById(productId);
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help :D

Answer (score -1):

Standard approach would be to retrieve the data directly from the method. This way the data gets retrieved only if you actually need it.

```
var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
DataTable billOfMaterial = productRepository.GetBillOfMaterial(productId);
```

It's safer to not use static repositories because of possible concurrency issues. 
If you are using .NET Core, you can also implement repository pattern with ASP.NET Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/repository-pattern?view=aspnetcore-2.1) with dependency injection.